# Neo4j - cypher query optimization

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am pretty new with Neo4j and we are trying to use it with our PHP SQL Server based application. I am using Neo4j 2.0 milestone 6. Some of the relevant configuration variables:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=5000
wrapper.java.maxmemory=5000
```

Now coming to the question- I am trying to write a cypher query which traverses graph and calculates allocation amount. Here is a snapshot of the structure of the graph.

[image]

Basically I have a department as a starting point which has certain amount and then it is allocated out to certain Product which in turn allocates out to other Products, so on. It can be n level deep allocation. Now I need to calculate amount for all the products.

The cypher query that I am using is as below:

```
MATCH (f:financial) WHERE f.amount <> 0 
WITH f
MATCH f-[r_allocates:Allocates*]->(n_allocation)
RETURN 
    n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id,  
    SUM(reduce(totalamt=f.amount, r IN r_allocates| (r.allocate)*totalamt/100 )) as amt 
ORDER BY n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id 
LIMIT 1000
```

This query takes 30+ seconds with warmed up caches. I have tried going back to Neo4j 1.9 as I found on some posts that Neo4j 2.0 is not yet optimized, but the similar query in 1.9 takes 40+ seconds.

Here is the output from profiler:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE2db722c4-6400-4803-90a2-b883b0076e8b"], returnItemNames=["n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id", "amt"], _rows=746, _db_hits=0)
==> Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id of type Any),true)"], limit="Literal(1000)", _rows=746, _db_hits=0)
==>   EagerAggregation(keys=["Cached(n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id of type Any)"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE2db722c4-6400-4803-90a2-b883b0076e8b,Sum(ReduceFunction(r_allocates,r,Divide(Multiply(Product(r,allocate(11),true),totalamt),Literal(100)),totalamt,Product(f,amount(9),true))))"], _rows=746, _db_hits=11680622)
==>     Extract(symKeys=["f", "n_allocation", "  UNNAMED55", "r_allocates"], exprKeys=["n_allocation.cost_pool_hierarchy_id"], _rows=3906768, _db_hits=3906768)
==>       PatternMatch(g="(f)-['  UNNAMED55']-(n_allocation)", _rows=3906768, _db_hits=0)
==>         Filter(pred="(NOT(Product(f,amount(9),true) == Literal(0)) AND hasLabel(f:financial(6)))", _rows=9959, _db_hits=34272)
==>           NodeByLabel(label="financial", identifier="f", _rows=34272, _db_hits=0)
```

I would appreciate any help in optimizing this query. Do I need to update some configuration settings? Or do I need to change the structure of graph?

**Update:**
Just to add further - even the below relatively simple query takes 26 seconds:

```
MATCH p=(f:financial)-[r*2]->(n)  RETURN COUNT(p)
```

Comment: how big is your data set?